# how to parse custom xml file in android

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

I have this `xml` file.

**test.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<playList baseUrl= "Webaddress">
<file name="xxxxxxx.xx1" showTime="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" />
<file name="xxxxxxx.xx2" showTime="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM" />
</playList>
```

This file is located into `sdcard`.Now i want to parse this xml.

I implement many demo but get **success**.

I am try to integrate [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/) example but get **IO Exception.**

**Please give me some suggestion or snippet of code.**

Comment: maybe post your trace log ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [parsing xml from the sdcard using XmlPullParser](http://qtcstation.com/2011/01/parsing-xml-from-the-sdcard-using-xmlpullparser/), In which they are using same which you are looking for. Let me know further query.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is helpful to begin

```
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try 
    {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
        is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
        doc = db.parse(is); 

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
        // return DOM
    return doc;
```

After that you create a function for this, then you have your Document

```
    Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
```

Then you can get elements like this for example :

```
NodeList n1_item = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM_DESC);
```

Comment: what is means parser and where to put?

Comment: I just saw that you are actually using the same things I do.
parser is the class where I put the fonction I gave you at first that is called getDomElement.
Gives us the error it will be more helpful :)